# What is __flexarr and how/why do c programmers use it?

Tags: c

In `sys/inotify.h` ([inotify.h](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/+/android-4.1.1_r6/sysroot/usr/include/sys/inotify.h)), following struct is defined:

```
struct inotify_event
{
  int wd;               /* Watch descriptor.  */
  uint32_t mask;        /* Watch mask.  */
  uint32_t cookie;      /* Cookie to synchronize two events.  */
  uint32_t len;         /* Length (including NULs) of name.  */
  char name __flexarr;  /* Name.  */
};
```

I can't find any definitions for `__flexarr` in the code. Where would I search for it?

In an unrelated project I found `#define __flexarr [1]` which I assume does something similar, but this definition does not make much sense to me (being quite unfamiliar with C).

The only thing I know is that you can store strings of various length in it, but I completely lack the understanding of how/why this works.

Does anybody care to explain? Thanks.

Comment: `flexarr` sounds like `Flexible array`. Perhaps the structure is dynamically allocated with a size greater than `sizeof(struct inotify_event)`? In that case perhaps name could be used to access a string of an arbitrary size.

Comment: @self. - in C99, you use `char flex[];` (for some type, with empty size) to create a flexible array member.  But I agree that the `__flexarr` is part of a struct hack.

Comment: @luiscubal Yes, name is used to reference a file name (which can be very long depending on the file system). I guess that is why they want a flexible structure. But I still don't understand why it is implemented like this. `char name [0]`, like @self suggested, still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I mean [] of course. Sneaky 0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the [struct hack](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html). C99 added it officially in the form of "flexible array member".

> As a special case, the last element of a structure with more than one
>   named member may have an incomplete array type; this is called a
>   flexible array member. In most situations, the flexible array member
>   is ignored. In particular, the size of the structure is as if the
>   flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more
>   trailing padding than the omission would imply.

The `sys/cdefs.h` I have says:

```
#if __GNUC_PREREQ (2,97)
/* GCC 2.97 supports C99 flexible array members.  */
# define __flexarr      []
#else
# ifdef __GNUC__
#  define __flexarr     [0]
# else
....
```

If you are writing new code, the standard-mandated way to use it is with just a `[]`.