# Does clang++ treat system headers in a more relaxed way?

Tags: c++, c, linux, clang, standards

The following struct is defined in the Linux system header file `/usr/include/sys/inotify.h`:

```
struct inotify_event
{
    int wd;
    uint32_t mask;
    uint32_t cookie;
    uint32_t len;
    char name __flexarr;
};
```

Please note the last field `name`, [which is a zero-length array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21589449/1708801). C++17 does not support zero-length array, so, if using `struct inotify_event` in a C++17 project and compiling it with `-pedantic`, a compiler warning should be raised.

However, the following code doesn't raise any warning for `struct inotify_event`. More weird, if I define a struct using zero-length array the same way, the warning is raised as expected.

Compiler options: **clang++ -std=c++17 -pedantic main.cpp**

```
#include <sys/inotify.h>

struct inotify_event* p = nullptr; // no warning

struct A
{
    int x;
    char name __flexarr; // warning: flexible array members are a C99 feature
};

int main()
{}
```

Is there any magic behind clang++ that treats system headers in a more relaxed way?

Comment: C99 isn't C++ much less C++17

Comment: I know, so I expect a warning under C++17.

Comment: Ah, my apologies.  I've been reading newbie questions all night :-/

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-in-system-headers

"Warnings are suppressed when they occur in system headers. By default, an included file is treated as a system header if it is found in an include path specified by -isystem, but this can be overridden in several ways."

Comment: Interesting I don't see it [defined that way here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/inotify.h) although it is a flexible array member there.

Comment: Note that __flexarr is a reserved identifier.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Some pre-C99 compilers require the use of `[0]` to achieve "treat space after structure as part of an array" semantics, some compilers require the use of `[]`, some will work equally well with either, and some can't handle such semantics at all.  If code is only expected to be used with a compiler that accepts one particular syntactic form, there's no need to try to handle both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any magic behind clang++ that treats system-defined headers in a more relaxed way?

Yes, if we look at the clang [documentation for Controlling Diagnostics in System Headers](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-in-system-headers) it says:

> **Warnings are suppressed when they occur in system headers**. By default, an included file is treated as a system header if it is found in an include path specified by `-isystem`, but this can be overridden in several ways.
>
> The `system_header` pragma can be used to mark the current file as being a system header. No warnings will be produced from the location of the pragma onwards within the same file.
>
> ```
> #if foo
> #endif foo // warning: extra tokens at end of #endif directive
>
> #pragma clang system_header
>
> #if foo
> #endif foo // no warning
> ```
>
> The `–system-header-prefix=` and `–no-system-header-prefix=` command-line arguments can be used to override whether subsets of an include path are treated as system headers. When the name in a `#include` directive is found within a header search path and starts with a system prefix, the header is treated as a system header. The last prefix on the command-line which matches the specified header name takes precedence.
>
> For instance:
>
> ```
> $ clang -Ifoo -isystem bar --system-header-prefix=x/ \
>     --no-system-header-prefix=x/y/
> ```
>
> Here, `#include "x/a.h"` is treated as including a system header, even if the header is found in `foo`, and `#include "x/y/b.h"` is treated as not including a system header, even if the header is found in `bar`.
>
> A `#include` directive which finds a file relative to the current directory is treated as including a system header if the including file is treated as a system header.