# let swig handle a c struct hack (__flexarray)

Tags: c#, c, swig

I'm trying to create c# wrapper code for linux' `inotify` and `inotifywait`.

Problem is that swig isn't able to handle the flex array struct hack used in `inotify`
swig version is 4.0.2 and inotify.h is from glib-headers 2.17-324 (according to `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/include/sys/inotify.h`)

```
struct inotify_event
{
   int wd;
   uint32_t mask;
   uint32_t cookie;
   uint32_t len;
   char name __flexarray; // <- this fails
}
```

According to [What is __flexarr and how/why do c programmers use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589449/what-is-flexarr-and-how-why-do-c-programmers-use-it) this is a struct hack and valid C99.

My swig-interface file looks like

```
%module mymodule
%{
#include "/usr/includes/sys/inotify.h"
#include "/usr/includes/inotifywait/inotifytools.h"
};

%include "/usr/includes/sys/inotify.h"
%include "/usr/includes/inotifywait/inotifytools.h"
```

when I call swig like `swigg -csharp -I/usr/include/inotifytools -I/usr/incldue/sys -Wall inotifybinding.i` it fails with the error `Syntax error - possibly a missing semicolon` and points to the line with the struct hack.

I then thought maybe I can just create my own version of `inotify_event` and ignore the declaration from `inotify.h` like

```
%{
struct inotify_event
{
   int wd;
   uint32_t mask;
   uint32_t cookie;
   uint32_t len;
   char name []; // <- should be the same as with __flexarray
}
// the #includes
};

%ignore inotify_event
// the %includes
```

Unfortunately the error perists and I need this struct because otherwise important functions like `inotifytools_next_event` return some kind of `cptr` which I don't know how to handle with C#.

I thought the ignore would basically just remove every declaration named `inotify_event` from the wrapper code but it seems that the %includes are validated before the %ignore is triggered.

Is there a way I can get `inotify_event` properly created in my wrapper code?

**EDIT:**: also the newest swig version doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWIG doesn't understand a lot of compiler-specific things, such as `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` on Windows, but if you look at `Lib\windows.i` in the SWIG installation, you'll see the preprocessor is used to remove them, e.g. `#define __cdecl`.

I don't have a way to verify this, but you might get away with the following to turn that unknown-to-SWIG compiler option to a more standard declaration:

```py
%module mymodule
%{
// included normally here
#include "/usr/includes/sys/inotify.h"
#include "/usr/includes/inotifywait/inotifytools.h"
};

#define __flexarray []    // turn "char name __flexarray;" into "char name[];"
%include "/usr/includes/sys/inotify.h"
%include "/usr/includes/inotifywait/inotifytools.h"
```

Comment: I accepted this as a solution since it solved the problem asked. For further information have a look and my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Tolonens solution did solve my initial problem but other problem with syntax errors etc. arose.
Respectively popped up not because Mark Tolonens suggestion broke something but because it solved the first problem and SWIG just stumbled over the next one.

After some digging I added the following header which solved all my problems.

```
%module mymodule
%{
#include "/usr/includes/sys/inotify.h"
#include "/usr/includes/inotifywait/inotifytools.h"
};

%include "/usr/includes/sys/cdefs.h" // <- add this line here
%include "/usr/includes/sys/inotify.h"
%include "/usr/includes/inotifywait/inotifytools.h"
```

With this line SWIG generated a c# class for `inotify_event` and some quick tests confirmed its working.

Alternatively you could do the marshaling yourself but with that you have to deal with memory allocations in c# etc.